# Como llamar y agregar un atributo de una datatable

Tags: javascript, datatables, datatable

Necesito hacer una condicion que cuando el selector de registro `pageLength` sea mayor que 10 le agregue a la datatable un `scrollY:300` y un `scrollX:true`, intente con la siguiente condicion y no funciona

```js
var table = $('#tblDistribucionZonas').DataTable({
  dom: 'lBfrtip',
  pageLength: 10,
  buttons: [
    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
  ],
  language: {
    "emptyTable": "No hay información",
    "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Documentos",
    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Documentos",
    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
    "infoPostFix": "",
    "thousands": ",",
    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Documentos",
    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "processing": "Procesando...",
    "search": "Buscar:",
    "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
    "paginate": {
      "first": "Primero",
      "last": "Ultimo",
      "next": "Siguiente",
      "previous": "Anterior"
    }
  }
});

if(pageLength > 10){
  $('#tblDistribucionZonas').DataTable({
    scrollX:true,
    scrollY:300
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Saludos podrías hacer algo como esto:

primero debemos seleccionar el valor del select del datatable algo asi:

```
var valor_seleccionado = $("select[name=id_table_length]").val();
```

si te fijas he puesto **id_table_length** alli solo debes cambiar por tu **ID** del table y seguido de tu id agregas **_length** .

una vez con este valor debes hacer tu condicion deseada con un if, ahora par asignar o cambiar los Scroll del datatable seria algo asi:

```
$('.dataTables_scrollBody').css('height', 300);
```

o en su defecto algo como esto:

```
$('#id_table').dataTable({'sScrollY': 100});
```

para mayor detalle te sugiero revisar esta respuesta donde dan distintas soluciones:
[Scroll Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685865/jquery-datatable-change-sscrolly)

Podrias hacer algo asi:

```
var valor_seleccionado = $("select[name=id_table_length]").val();
if(valor_seleccionado >10){
  $('.dataTables_scrollBody').css('height', 300);
}
```

Comment: Viejo me sirvio lo del contador pero necesito es agregar los dos scroll `scrollX:true` y `scrollY:300` cuando se hace la condicion de que pasa de 10

Comment: por ello solo debes hacer la condicion con el valor que recibes del contador

Comment: por eso ya hice la condicion `if(valor_seleccionado > 10){ aqui necesito lo de los scroll}`

Comment: exacto ya edite mi respuesta prueba como lo hice yo..!!

Comment: Es que no me sirve porque todavia no tengo el scroll lo que necesito es agregarle ese atributo a la datatable, porque la tabla esta sin los dos scroll ni el x ni el y, entonces cuando pasa de 10 filas ahi es cuando necesito agregarle los dos atributos por medio de la condicion pero no me sirve porque estoy es agregando un css y necesito es el atributo como tal

Comment: prueba con esto: $('#id_table').dataTable({'sScrollY': 100});

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90399/discussion-between-julian-andres-candamil-and-diego-avila).

Answer (score 0):

No se como agregarle un atributo a una tabla ya definida. pero ps para hacer lo que dices yo lo que hago es destruir la definición del datatable y crearla de nuevo pero con los nuevos valores de los atributos

```
  let parametrosDataTable={
  dom: 'lBfrtip',
  pageLength: 10,
  buttons: [
    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
  ],
  language: {
    "emptyTable": "No hay información",
    "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Documentos",
    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Documentos",
    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
    "infoPostFix": "",
    "thousands": ",",
    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Documentos",
    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "processing": "Procesando...",
    "search": "Buscar:",
    "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
    "paginate": {
      "first": "Primero",
      "last": "Ultimo",
      "next": "Siguiente",
      "previous": "Anterior"
    }
  }
}
var table = $('#tblDistribucionZonas').DataTable(parametrosDataTable);

if(pageLength > 10){
  table.destroy()
  parametrosDataTable.scrollX=true
  parametrosDataTable.scrollY=300
  table = $('#tblDistribucionZonas').DataTable(parametrosDataTable);
}
```